# (SQR 4008) Unknown function or variable in expression

Tags: error-handling, special-characters, peoplesoft, sqr

I have an SQR code like this:

**begin-procedure SPL-REMOVE($Vndr_Name_Shrt_Usr, :$outputshrt)**

**Let $valid_chars_shrt = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -.:/'@0123456789@()=+%*"£$'**

**Let $invalid_chars_shrt = translate($Vndr_Name_Shrt_Usr, $valid_chars_shrt, '')**

**Let #invalid_shrt = length($invalid_chars_shrt)**

**If #invalid_shrt**

**Let $outputshrt = translate($Vndr_Name_Shrt_Usr, $invalid_chars_shrt, '')**

**Else**

**Let $outputshrt = $Vndr_Name_Shrt_Usr**

**End-if**

**end-procedure**

And upon running the SQR, I am getting this error:

(SQR 4008) Unknown function or variable in expression: @0123456789@
Let $valid_chars_shrt = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -.:/'@0123456789@()=+%*"£$'

May I know why is that so? How can I avoid such error from coming up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is truly the code:
Let $valid_chars_shrt = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -.:/'@0123456789@()=+%*"£$'

The problem lies with the single quote before the @012345678.  It unbalances the quoted string.  Change it to TWO single quotes '' (not a double-quote).  That should work but unless I test it, no guarantees.

Comment: You gave me an idea on it! Although I made some tweaks on other part of the code to jive in, but later then I realized about the confusing apostrophe on that particular code.